# What is the difference between hook_field_attach_validate() and hook_field_validate()?

Tags: hooks

I'm a bit confused as for the difference between these two hooks,  and which one I should use for custom  validation of attached fields in my code.

Is there a better way to define a custom validation for an attached field (I am attaching the field programatically if that helps)?

EDIT: Looking more into it, I don't really get all that much information in `hook_field_attach_validate()`. All I'm pretty much getting is the entity_type, entity object and an errors array.

Whereas with `hook_field_validate()`, I get the field I'm actually validating against, which, I'm assuming is where I need to put the bulk of my custom field validation logic. The only issue I'm having now is that I'm unable to find a function that will invoke this method for me. Should I manually invoke this function or is there an API function I can use in this instance?

Answer (score 2):

[hook_field_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7)
 Should be used to validate the form for your modules fields.

[hook_field_attach_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_validate/7) works on [field_attach_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_validate/7) which is more for back end validation.

> This function does not perform field widget validation on form
>   submissions. It is intended to be called during API save operations.
>   Use field_attach_form_validate() to validate form submissions.

Are the fields ones which your modules is creating, or are they fields from a third party module?

The [#element_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate) property may be what you need to validate another modules fields.

Comment: I'm creating custom fields based on the default field types: i.e. creating a city field using field_create_field() with a 'text' field type. In this case, would I use #element_validate?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else like me finds this old question, here is a bit more information based on my own experiments and searching.

- There is now a D7 module [Field Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation).
- It looks as if hook_field_validate() is only called for the module that defines the field, so that's no good for a standard field.
- If you use #element_validate I think it would only affect the standard edit form - so for example not edits via View Bulk Operations.  Maybe this doesn't matter to many people.
- You can use hook_field_attach_validate(), as it is called from form validation in field_attach_form_validate().  This hook is what the Field Validation module uses.  Everything you need is inside the entity parameter.

Sample code below validates a phone number for the UK.

```
function XXX_field_attach_validate($entity_type, $entity, &$errors) {
  if (!empty($entity->field_telephone_number)) {
    foreach ($entity->field_telephone_number as $langcode => $items) {
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        if (!preg_match('/^0(\s*\d){9,10}$/', $item['value'])) {
          $errors ['field_telephone_number'][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
            'error' => 'XXX_telephone_number',
            'message' => t('Telephone number must be 10 or 11 digits starting with 0.'),
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```