# Field API - which hook to use?

Tags: entities

I have successfully created a field with my module and managed to show it on user registration form. The next step would be validating my field. There are two hooks for this, and I'm confused as to which one to use. One is hook_field_validate and the other is hook_field_attach_validate. I'm also confused as to how to refer to the field. **$instance['user']['field_tckn_no']**? (This is what dpm(field_info_instances('user') shows me. Also, one thing that confuses me is that hook_field_validate iterates over the fields but all I have is one field. Is it still the one to use?

Regards,
K.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail how you defined this field and added it to the user entity? Can you share the relevant code you've written so far?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/8336/1899

Comment: @marcvangend I've used field_create_field to create the field I've defined, and field_create_instance to attach it to 'user' entity. My .install file is at http://ur1.ca/i4zvi and my .module at http://ur1.ca/i4zxz. I didn't paste them here worried about how to format them.

Comment: Many apologies for my previous answer (now deleted) my understanding of the question was well off.

Comment: No problem at all, it happens :)

Comment: I've just tried a `dpm($entity)` in `hook_field_attach_validate` implementation, and it didn't get picked up when I filled the values in, and hit `Apply for an account`. Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, at last I was able to figure it out. Since the field was part of the form after creating the instance, I thought I could use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), and I was right!